# Large C code not compiling with MATLAB's mex

Tags: c, matlab, mex

My overall goal is to use a C model inside my MATLAB code.  The C model is large (over a dozen .c files, which are all run from cModel.c) and can be successfully compiled then run in the terminal by

```
make cModel
cModel.x startingfile.inp
```

as the C model is correctly built for normal C compilers.

However, MATLAB's mex function is not compiling this C code.  I'm a total novice with mex and I am pulling my hair out trying to understand what the problem is.

I think (and reading some similar problems on stackoverflow backs this up) that the problem is around creating a mexFunction.  My attempt currently is

```
/*function AA_mexWrapper.c*/
/*Include the MATLAB mex header*/
#include "mex.h"

/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction( )
{
/* Main() of the C Model*/
cModel(); /* cModel writes files.  We don't care about the nonexistant returned variables*/
}
```

This generates the error (using mex AA_mexWrapper cModel) :

```
Error using mex
/Users/Filepath/ cModel.c:215:5: warning:
implicit declaration of function 'main' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-    function-declaration]
main(int argc, char **argv);
^
/Users/Filepath/ cModel.c:215:10: error:
expected expression
main(int argc, char **argv);
     ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

What is MATLAB doing and how do I fix it?  I really just need it to treat cModel.c like a normal C compiler would.

PS.  I have no idea what (int argc, char **argv) are in the C code.  They are totally undefined, presumably they come from the optional user input of a filename containing non-default parameters for the model.

PPS.  I will need to run the C model inside matlab by pointing it to a text file containing various model options.  I hope that MATLAB can deal with this, but I'm starting to have my doubts...

Comment: Use correct function declarators. The ones you use are outdated since 1989.

Comment: @Olaf - I didn't write the C model unfortunately.  What is the problem with them?

Comment: If you are not going to pass any variables into or out of the mex function from MATLAB variables, there is no point to compiling the code with mex.  Just use "system" to call your executable built the normal way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call an executable like a function; the name of the executable is not "exported" the way you might think.

How about a simple solution? build your executable outside MATLAB and ask MATLAB to just run it; here's a piece of code that would do that (assuming that the `cModel.x` is in the same folder as the script/function that calls it):

```
system('./cModel.x startingfile.inp');
```

Comment: Perfect.

I can use that to get exactly the functionality I need.  Thanks for noticing the problem in my approach - I did not know about the system command.